# Inequality : $a+b^{\frac{2}{3}}+c^{\frac{1}{3}}\geq 3$ with some conditions

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I have the following problem to solve :

> Let $a,b,c>0$ with $a\geq b \geq c$ such that $a^3+b^3+c^3=3$ and $a^3\in[1,3-2p]$,$b^3\in[p,1]$,$c^3\in[p,1]$ then we have :
>   $$a+b^{\frac{2}{3}}+c^{\frac{1}{3}}\geq 3$$Where $p$ verify :$$p^{\frac{1}{9}}+p^{\frac{2}{9}}+(3-2p)^{\frac{1}{3}}=3$$

The main idea is the following lemma :

> Let $b,c$ verify the conditions above then we have :
>    $$b^{\frac{2}{3}}+c^{\frac{1}{3}}\geq (\frac{b+c}{2})^{\frac{2}{3}}+(\frac{b+c}{2})^{\frac{1}{3}}$$

It's not hard to prove and with this lemma we can put $b=c$

Remains to study the following function :

$$f(p)=p^{\frac{1}{9}}+p^{\frac{2}{9}}+(3-2p)^{\frac{1}{3}}-3$$

After this I'm a little bit stuck .

If you have an other way or if you can complete my proof it would be nice

Thanks a lot for your time .

Comment: Is it means $c\in[1,p]$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $[1;p]$?. If you meant interval, then the notation is $[1,p]$. If you meant two distinct points $1$ and $p$, then you should have used $ {1,p} $ . However, the problem itself is trivial if you meant $[1,p]$, for then we are forced to have $a=b=c=1$